# Generic templates or templates in models - Django

Tags: django, django-templates

What is the best approach in a following situation?

Say we have some models, e.g. `Article`, `Photo`, `BlogEntry` and so on. Every model can be displayed on the page as a thumb or a so-called widget.

Example:

- attribute `thumbview` of a model contains item thumb with title in html block
- `normalview` - contains larger thumb, title and description in a block
- `bigview` - thumb, title, description and say... number of comments addded

All of these should be in some way polymorphic in a template so I could do something like iterating through my list of abstract items (various types) and simply:

```
{{ item.thumbview }}
```

or

```
{{ item.bigview }}
```

to display every item thumb.

It can be achieved lazy-evaluated in a model but I don't feel hardcode'ing html in a model is the right way.

How can I model such a behaviour? What is the best way?

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom template tag and a standard method in a model to give a context to the widget in case you can't achieve some properties in a template:

`myapp/models.py`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    def widget_context(self, context):  # receives the context of the template.
        user = context['request'].user  # context should be RequestContext to contain request object (or you may use thread locals).
        return {'tags': self.tag_set.filter(...), 'can_edit': self.owner == user or user.is_admin}
```

template tags file, `widgets_app/templatetags/objwidgets.py`:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def object_widget(context, obj, size='small'):
    context_func = getattr(obj, 'widget_context')  # try getting the context method
    extra_context = context_func(context) if context_func else {}
    extra_context['obj'] = obj

    long_tuple = (obj._meta.app_label, 'widgets', obj.__class__.__name__, size)
    return render_to_string([  # multiple templates to have both generic and specific templates
        '%s/%s/%s.%s.html' % long_tuple, # the most specific (photos/widgets/photo.small.html)
        '%s/widget.%s.%s.html' % (obj._meta.app_label, obj.__class__.__name__, size),
        '%s/widget.%s.html' % (obj._meta.app_label, size), # myapp/widget.small.html
        'widget.%s.html' % size,
    ],
    extra_context
    context)
```

usage:

```
{% load objwidgets %}
{% object_widget photo1 'large' %}
{% object_widget photo2 %}
```

make a template for the object widget, `myapp/widgets/photo.small.html`:

```
<b>{{ obj.name }}</b>
<img src="{{ obj.thumbnail.url }}"/>
{% if can_edit %}<a href="{{ obj.get_edit_url }}">edit</a>{% endif %}
{% for t in tags %}
    <a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.text }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: _After few days of coding_ - this approach is simply awesome! It encourages DRY in great way, makes developing faster and cleaner.  The best Django advice on SO for me ever :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't generate html at all in your model. You can write [some custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to achieve what you need. If you are using django dev version, you can create an inclusion tag with an argument that could return a piece of html depending on the model type of the input.